# MultiActionController no longer receiving requests?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, controller, tomcat6

I was attempting to make changes to my controller, and all of a sudden, I no longer seem to receive any requests (404 when attempting to hit the servlet mapped URLs). I'm sure I've broken my `web.xml` or `app-servlet.xml`, but I just don't see where. I can access `index.jsp` from tomcat (`http://IP/app/index.jsp`), but I can't get my servlet mapping to work correctly.

Help?

web.xml:

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app 
    PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN" 
    "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd">
<web-app version = "2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>app</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>app</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/myRequest</url-pattern>
</servet-mapping>
```

app-servlet.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN//EN" "http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans.dtd">
<beans>
     <bean id = "MyController" class = "com.stefankendall.MyController" ></bean>

     <bean id="urlMappingDeployment" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
      <property name="mappings">
         <props>
             <prop key="/myRequest">MyController</prop>
         </props>
      </property>
   </bean>

</beans>
```

Comment: Please include more detail, from what I see you have no page, that will give you a 404.  You have no welcome page specified, and you've mapped that controller only to the name "/myRequest", only that specific URL will even be sent on to the app-servlet.xml.  What are you trying to accomplish when you go to yoursite/myRequest?

Comment: It's a simple web service. I'm just testing a concept. I ONLY need that URL to be passed on, yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your controller mapping should look more like this, first off, but your URL "pattern" looks fishy too, a pattern is rarely a static string as you have it, but if what you want is the URL "/myRequest" mapped to your controller the following is all you need:

```
<bean name = "/myRequest" class = "com.stefankendall.MyController" ></bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

`<url-pattern>/myRequest</url-pattern>` should be `<url-pattern>/myRequest/*</url-pattern>`